# Which device initiates the data exchange in OSPF (is it the master device or slave)?

Tags: routing, ospf

I want to know which device initiates the data exchange in OSPF protocol (master device or slave device).

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

From "OSPF version 2" [RFC 2328](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2328)

During the Hello phase, every router sends packets:

> Hello packets are sent periodically out all router interfaces. (section 7.1)

During database synchronisation, the master leads:

> Database Description Packets sent by the master (polls) are acknowledged by the slave (section 7.2)